# Grey bar on left in vim?

Tags: linux, vim

I get a grey bar on left side in vim for one file. This does not happen for any other file. What is this? And how to get rid of it?

EDIT:

This is what it looks like: This goes on for the full height of the file. It does not appear in any other files. The file is a `*.C` which is correctly identified as of `cpp` file type but this thing does not happen to other files where they are being identified as `cpp`. `colourscheme` is `default`

[image]

EDIT2:
Here is the view file for the file:

```
let s:so_save = &so | let s:siso_save = &siso | set so=0 siso=0
argglobal
setlocal keymap=
setlocal noarabic
setlocal autoindent
setlocal nobinary
setlocal bufhidden=
setlocal buflisted
setlocal buftype=
setlocal cindent
setlocal cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
setlocal cinoptions=
setlocal cinwords=if,else,while,do,for,switch
setlocal comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-
setlocal commentstring=/*%s*/
setlocal complete=.,w,b,u,t,i
setlocal completefunc=
setlocal nocopyindent
setlocal nocursorcolumn
setlocal nocursorline
setlocal define=
setlocal dictionary=
setlocal diff
setlocal equalprg=
setlocal errorformat=
setlocal expandtab
if &filetype != 'cpp'
setlocal filetype=cpp
endif
setlocal foldcolumn=2
setlocal foldenable
setlocal foldexpr=0
setlocal foldignore=#
setlocal foldlevel=0
setlocal foldmarker={{{,}}}
setlocal foldmethod=diff
setlocal foldminlines=1
setlocal foldnestmax=20
setlocal foldtext=foldtext()
setlocal formatexpr=
setlocal formatoptions=tcq
setlocal formatlistpat=^\\s*\\d\\+[\\]:.)}\\t\ ]\\s*
setlocal grepprg=
setlocal iminsert=0
setlocal imsearch=0
setlocal include=
setlocal includeexpr=
setlocal indentexpr=
setlocal indentkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
setlocal noinfercase
setlocal iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
setlocal keywordprg=
setlocal nolinebreak
setlocal nolisp
setlocal nolist
setlocal makeprg=
setlocal matchpairs=(:),{:},[:]
setlocal nomodeline
setlocal modifiable
setlocal nrformats=octal,hex
setlocal nonumber
setlocal numberwidth=4
setlocal omnifunc=
setlocal path=
setlocal nopreserveindent
setlocal nopreviewwindow
setlocal quoteescape=\\
setlocal noreadonly
setlocal norightleft
setlocal rightleftcmd=search
setlocal scrollbind
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal noshortname
setlocal smartindent
setlocal softtabstop=0
setlocal nospell
setlocal spellcapcheck=[.?!]\\_[\\])'\"\    \ ]\\+
setlocal spellfile=
setlocal spelllang=en
setlocal statusline=
setlocal suffixesadd=
setlocal swapfile
setlocal synmaxcol=3000
if &syntax != 'cpp'
setlocal syntax=cpp
endif
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal tags=
setlocal textwidth=0
setlocal thesaurus=
setlocal nowinfixheight
setlocal nowinfixwidth
setlocal nowrap
setlocal wrapmargin=0
let s:l = 75 - ((20 * winheight(0) + 29) / 59)
if s:l < 1 | let s:l = 1 | endif
exe s:l
normal! zt
75
normal! 0
let &so = s:so_save | let &siso = s:siso_save
doautoall SessionLoadPost
" vim: set ft=vim
```

Comment: The bar might be a [foldcolumn](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-foldcolumn)? It's hard to say based on color, since everyone has their own colorschemes.

Comment: can you put your vim cursor over the bar?

Comment: If you're still into vim here's a good book http://amzn.to/Uoz2Nd that answers many of the configuration questions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

:set foldcolumn=0

Comment: nakiya: Fold column indicates open and closed folds in the buffer.  See `:help folding` for more details.

Comment: @nakiya I get the bar after running `diffsplit`. `help diff` says that `foldcolumn` defaults to 2 for diff mode. `diffoff!` resets the options that `diff` set. There are probably other commands that set `foldcolumn`.

Answer (score 26):

In my case, no others but below was the solution.

```
set signcolumn=no
```

Comment: Fixes it right away. It happens after enabling LSP on neovim atleast on my side.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like some plugin creates a sign. Try doing

```
sign unplace *
```

To find where this plugin is located, try

```
vim /path/to/file/that/causes/problem -c 'redir! >/tmp/scriptnames' -c scriptnames -c 'redir END' -c 'qa!'
perl -p -i -e 's/^\s*$//g;s/^\s*\d+:\s//g' /tmp/scriptnames
grep -F -w 'sign define' `cat /tmp/scriptnames`
```

Comment: @ZyX Could you provide a little more insight into what this command actually does or direct us to documentation?

Comment: @meetalexjohnson Which command? First is described in `:h :sign` and simply unplaces all signs (note about signs: defining sign creates a structure with some metadata, but does not actually cause Vim to display anything. Placing sign creates a connection between a sign and a pair `(buffer, line number)` and makes Vim display the sign when buffer is displayed). Block with three commands (1) captures the output of `:scriptnames` (`:h :scriptnames`) to a file, (2) uses perl to leave only file names and (3) checks whether any of the sourced files contains `sign define`.

Comment: This proved to be the case for me: when I made a change to a C file and saved it it would show up. I did `:help sign` and I saw something that looked familiar (and when I undid the change and save again it went away). Then I tried `:sign list` and found the problem: I was playing with Syntastic the other day and it was this, it seems, that's the problem. Edit: Yes that was it. Thanks for the pointer to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

There can be a few reasons for this. One may be a modeline. Modeline is a special line at the beginning or end of a file that sets specific settings for Vim for that file. Look for a comment line (or a line that starts with a blank), followed by the word `vim` and a space. Any text following that in the line may be of interest in debugging this.

Another option may be that the file has a specific `filetype` that triggers an `autocommand` set in your .vimrc file or one of its sourced modules. In particular look for `set number`, `relativenumber`, `colorcolumn`, `foldcolumn` or maybe even specific highlight settings for blanks. In Vim within the relevant buffer enter `:set ft?` followed by a carriage-return to know the filetype set for that file; use this to look at the settings for that filetype in your vimrc or the highlight settings in your .vim directory tree.

Comment: Tried modeline - did not work. And there are no autocommands for `cpp` type.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add you can tell which script set the option by using

```
:verbose set foldcolumn?
```

You can replace foldcolumn with any name that you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for this is something being in a modeline - a line with contents like "vi:" or "vim:" or "ex:" in it, and something is then after it which is being interpreted as an option. See `:help modeline` for more information. I can't think off the top of my head what options could make it look like that.

Try doing `:set nomodeline` and reload the file - if that fixes it, the file has a modeline (whether you intended it to have or not). Then you can see about fixing it, or disabling modeline support if you wish in your vimrc.